# Hex string to UnsafePointer<Int8> swift

Tags: swift, string, hex, unsafe-pointers, unsafemutablepointer

I am looking a better way to convert a hex string to an array of UnsafePointer. here is my current code:

```
let pointer: UnsafePointer<Int8>? = NSString(string: "d0c6a560de2e60b6ac55386defefdf93b0c907290c2ad1b4dbd3338186bfdc68").utf8String
// or 
let pointer: UnsafePointer<Int8>? = NSString(string: key).utf8String
let length = NSString(string: key).length
var res =  blsSecretKeySetHexStr(&sec, pointer, length)
```

I'm porting a [C++ class](https://github.com/herumi/bls) to Swift and this class methods **blsSecretKeySetHexStr** and **blsPublicKeyGetHexStr** require **UnsafePointer** and **UnsafeMutablePointer** as input.

Comment: The real question is: Why do you need an `UnsafePointer<Int8>` ? Do you want do *decode* the hex string?

Comment: @MartinR I am porting a C++ class to swift

Comment: I suggest that you describe (in the question) more detailed what you actually want to do.

Comment: @MartinR the post edited.

Comment: Do you want to *port* (i.e. convert) C++ to Swift, or do you want to *call* C++ functions from Swift?

Comment: @MartinR calling the functions using cpp headers

Comment: Are you aware that you cannot import C++ APIs to Swift, only C APIs?

Comment: @MartinR I’m importing as static binary class

Answer (score 1):

You can find useful informations about `UnsafePointer` usage [here](https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift3/se-0107-migrate.html#common-use-cases).

First if you have want to pass a pointer to a string to a function accepting an `UnsafePointer<Int8>` you can simply do :

```swift
func foo(pointer: UnsafePointer<Int8>) {
    print(pointer) // 0x0000600003478c60
    print(strlen(pointer)) // 64
}

let immutableString = "d0c6a560de2e60b6ac55386defefdf93b0c907290c2ad1b4dbd3338186bfdc68"

foo(pointer: immutableString)
// 0x0000600003478c60
// 64
```

or

```swift
let cStringPointer = immutableString.utf8CString
    .withUnsafeBufferPointer { $0 }
    .baseAddress!
foo(pointer: cStringPointer)
// 0x0000600003478c60
// 64
```

or

```swift
var cstring = immutableString.cString(using: .utf8)!
foo(pointer: &cstring)
// 0x00006000023e0950
// 64
```

if you need an `UnsafeMutablePointer` :

```swift
func bar(pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>) {
    print(pointer)
    print(strlen(pointer))
}

let string = "d0c6a560de2e60b6ac55386defefdf93b0c907290c2ad1b4dbd3338186bfdc68"
var cstring = string.cString(using: .utf8)!
bar(pointer: &cstring)
// 0x00006000023e0950
// 64
```

or

```swift
var mutableCString = immutableString.utf8CString
let mutableCStringPointer = mutableCString
    .withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { $0 }
    .baseAddress!
bar(pointer: cStringMutablePointer)
// 0x0000600003478c60
// 64
```